# Why do I get an error(?)?

Tags: jsp

I'm typing this code.

```
<%
    int a = 5, b = 10;
    boolean what; 
    boolean c = true, d = false;

    out.print("a :" + a + " b :" + b + "<P>");
    out.print("a<b :" + (a > b) + "<P>");

    out.print("a<=b :" + (a <= b) + "<P>");
    out.print("a==b :" + (a == b) + "<P>");
    out.print("a>b :" + (a > b) + "<P>");
    out.print("a>=b :" + (a >= b) + "<P>");
    out.print("c :" + c + "d :" + d + "<P>");
    out.print("c&&d :" + (c && d) + "<P>");
    out.print("c||d :" + (c || d) + "<P>");
    what = a > b ? true : false;
    out.print("a>b? " + what + ", !(a>b)=" + !what);
%>
```

but, result is above.

```
a :5 b :10

aa<=b :true

a==b :false

a>b :false

a>=b :false

c :trued :false

c&&d :false

c||d :true

a>b? false, !(a>b)=true
```

where is `(a<b)` code?
and I'm not typing `<b>`. but, sentence is bold.

Comment: right click in your browser on "show as html code".

Comment: <body>
 a = 5b = 10<P>a<b = true<P>a<=b = true<P>a==b = false<P>a>b = false<P>a>=b = false<P>c = trued = false<P>c&&d = false<P>c||d = true<P>a>b? false, !(a>b)=true
</body>

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna use `&lt;` instead of `<` and `&gt;` instead of `>`.

`a<b`  should be `a&lt;b`

You're getting bold because the html is interpretted as a `<b>` tag which stands for `bold font`.